# Meteor 100% uptime considering sticky sessions

Tags: session, meteor

I've been working with Meteor for some time and I'm considering using it for multiple large scale projects. I love Meteor and I really want to push it's adoption in our company but I have 1 last reservation before I do so. Sticky sessions and what it means for 100% uptime.

My requirement is 100% uptime for all of our sites. Hot code pushes obviously solve the problem of pushing new features/update/bug fixes. However, if a server needs to be taken down for maintenance, then all my active users are going to lose their sessions (something I can't let happen).

I was hoping someone may have some insights into the problem and what they've done to overcome it or if there's a possible strategy for migrating users from one server to another (session replication) thus preventing users from being kicked.

*The reason I ask is because the publish cursor keeps track of whatever collections the client may have so if the server disconnects and the client connection is directed to another server (because it's behind a load balancer), that server will not have any idea of what is out of sync on the client and create strange behaviour.*

Comment: have a look at this. It might be a lead towards what you're aiming for: https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status

Comment: The best resource I know of for this is Arunoda's bulletproofmeteor lesson on deployment architecture, https://bulletproofmeteor.com/architecture/deploying-a-highly-available-meteor-cluster, and in particular re: load balancing with sticky sessions the subsection on kubernetes. i hesitate to try to summarize it as i'm no expert, and it is behind a pay wall. but i've read and recommend it and you can use his strategy to scale w/ sticky sessions as needed. galaxy will probably take care of all of this much more seamlessly once it is ready.